# how to manage .htaccess in hostinger?

Tags: webserver, web-hosting, vimeo-api

I'm trying to upload large video in my web app and send it to vimeo api server-side and my web hosting provider is hostinger, i follow the instructions on their page (this is the link: https://www.hostinger.ph/tutorials/php-maximum-upload-size) on how to maximize the file size so that i can upload large files, I set the values  into this

```
php_value upload_max_filesize -1
php_value post_max_size -1
php_value max_input_time 0
php_value max_execution_time -1
```

but still I'm getting error of this. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WdbDn.png)(the website has cloudflare security) after two minutes , the video is about 1.2gb, The minimum to upload is 1gb what will be other solution to this? ,,

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want max_input_time = -1 and max_execution_time = 0.
These values seem to be reversed.

Other questions:

- Are the PHP values recognised when viewing the configuration in phpinfo()?
- Does the error occur for small uploads? I.e. are any uploads successful with the current configuration?
- How long does it take for the page to time out? I.e. is it consistent for uploads of different sizes?

The documentation advises that "the post_max_size should always be larger than upload_max_filesize to avoid an error when uploading". You may want to set explicit values for testing. E.g. 1500M

Finally, there may be other values (possibly outside of your control) affecting the upload. E.g. memory_limit should be larger than post_max_size.